# Share properties file and extend it between multiples spring boot projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, configuration

I have this problem.

In my app, I have **2** projects, **Bank** and **User** that connect to the **same database**, then both projects are the **same database configuration** in their application.properties. I don't want duplicate the configuration, then I had thought I could put that database configuration on the other properties(**common properties**) and in both properties extend that configuration.`

In Both projects(Bank, User) I have the same database configuration, the unique difference is the server.port, my **idea** is to have other properties(**common.properties**) that contains the database configuration, Bank and user properties, extends the common properties and add only server.port

```
#database
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:42333/userDatabase
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true

#server
server.port= 8090
```

My doubt It is possible to have inheritance between properties?

Thanks for your time and sorry for my englis, it is not my native languaje, Regards!

Comment: -externalized configuration is what you might be looking for: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html.

Comment: I would suggest to give links of up-to-date versions of Spring https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

Answer (score 2):

You can use spring cloud config

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).